# How to disable a hl-anything in orgmode?

Tags: org-mode, init-file, hooks

I'm trying to disable `hl-anything` only when I'm using `org-mode` or `org-agenda-mode` but I don't know how to do it.

I have tried this:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (hl-highlight-mode nil)))
```

And this:

```el
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (hl-highlight-mode nil)))
```

Comment: I haven't tried this mode but passing in `nil` for some modes may turn the mode on; try passing in `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hl-highlight-mode` is a global minor mode, and you can't disable a global minor mode on a per-buffer basis -- only buffer-local minor modes work that way. A global mode is either on or off globally.

Original answer about buffer-local minor modes follows...

---

The docstring at <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `hl-highlight-mode` should tell you exactly what its argument does, so just follow that information.

In recent versions of Emacs, modes defined by `define-minor-mode` are explicitly **enabled** when called from elisp with a `nil`argument.

This is to ensure consistent behaviour for the likes of `(add-hook 'HOOK 'MINORMODEFUNCTION)` -- which results in MINORMODEFUNCTION being called without its optional argument, which is the same thing as passing it an argument of `nil`.

i.e. your code:

```el
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (hl-highlight-mode nil)))
```

is equivalent to:

```el
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 'hl-highlight-mode)
```

Prior to that, a `nil` argument to a minor mode function would **toggle** the mode (just like calling the mode interactively); but that might be toggling it on or off depending on circumstances, so it wasn't a dependable thing to use in non-interactive cases.

*In general* a positive numeric argument enables a minor mode, and a non-positive (<= 0) argument disables it. In practice one mostly sees values of `0` or `-1` used to disable modes. For modes defined by `define-minor-mode` there is no difference between those two values.

---

edit:

Note that if `hl-highlight-mode` were being enabled via a *globalized* minor mode, it's trickier, and you may need to use `after-change-major-mode-hook`:

```el
(defun my-inhibit-globalized-hl-highlight-mode ()
  "Counter-act a globalized hl-highlight-mode."
  (add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
            (lambda () (hl-highlight-mode 0))
            :append :local))

(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 'my-inhibit-globalized-hl-highlight-mode)
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/6837511

Comment: Awesome answer @phils thank you! But it doesn't work here. When the minor mode is enable it does not disable it when I change to org-agenda-mode.

Comment: More information needed, then. For starters, what is `hl-highlight-mode` and where did you get it from? And how are you currently enabling it?

Comment: Ok, I get it from ELPA. The repo is https://github.com/hl-anything/hl-anything-emacs and I'am enabling with `M-x hl-highlight-mode` because `(hl-highlight-mode)` or `(hl-higlight-mode 1)` doesn't work.

Comment: Answer updated. It's a global mode, so you can't do what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you Phils. I didn't know about global minor modes... so.. thank you! :)